# how to find timestamp in point in time restore

Tags: mongodb

1) Created test DB.

2) Created document in collection mycol.

```
db.mycol.insert({
   _id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902c),
   title: 'MongoDB Overview', 
   description: 'MongoDB is no sql database',
   by: 'tutorials point',
   url: 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com',
   tags: ['mongodb', 'database', 'NoSQL'],
   likes: 100
})
```

3) AT 12 P.M, updated the doc

```
db.mycol.update({'title':'MongoDB Overview'},{$set:{'title':'New MongoDB Tutorial'}})
```

4) AT 3 P.M, deleted the doc

```
db.mycol.remove({'title':'MongoDB Overview'})
```

I have followed below steps to apply point in time restore before delete operation was happened.

**Step 1**: Taken oplog backup

```
mongodump -h <hostname:port> -d local -c oplog.rs -o oplogD
```

**Step 2**: Move and rename this `"oplog.rs.bson"` file to `"oplog.bson`"

```
mkdir oplogR
mv oplogD/local/oplog.rs.bson oplogR/oplog.bson
```

**step 3**: How to find the timestamp of the before delete operation has happened so that I can pass below restore command.

```
mongorestore -h <hostname:port> --oplogReplay --oplogLimit <timestamp> oplogR
```